# Don't want to display WARNING: ACTIONS REQUIRED: while running powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I have written bitlocker code to backup key after old key has been shared with user.

My requirement is that don't want to display WARNING: ACTIONS REQUIRED: while running script

[image]

```
$BLV = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint "C:"
$KeyProt = $BLV.KeyProtector | Where-object{$_.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword"}
$KeyProt.KeyProtectorId
Remove-BitlockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "C:" -KeyProtectorId $KeyProt.KeyProtectorId
Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "C:" -RecoveryPasswordProtector
$BLV = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint "C:"
$KeyProt = $BLV.KeyProtector | Where-object{$_.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword"}
$KeyProt.KeyProtectorId
Backup-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "C:" -KeyProtectorId $KeyProt.KeyProtectorId
Resume-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:"
```

Comment: Which of your commands displays this warning?

Comment: @harrymc this line `Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "C:" -RecoveryPasswordProtector`

Comment: @harrymc tried using out-null but didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows PowerShell has many more streams than Linux.

Here's the list from Microsoft's
[about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3):

[image]

You may redirect all streams using the wildcard `*>$null`.
You may also use a file instead of `$null`.

Reference :
[Redirecting output to $null in PowerShell, but ensuring the variable remains set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881174/redirecting-output-to-null-in-powershell-but-ensuring-the-variable-remains-set).

---

An alternative is to add to the `Add-BitLockerKeyProtector` command
the parameter `-ErrorVariable out` to store the error message in
variable `out`.

Or if this isn't an error message, perhaps
`-InformationVariable out`.

For more information see
[about_CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3).

Comment: i don't want to redirect. i don't want it to display

Comment: Try adding the parameter `-ErrorVariable out` to store the error message in variable `out`. Or if this isn't an error message, perhaps `-InformationVariable out`. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @SurajKumar - So what was the full command?

Comment: Linux has up to 256 file descriptors (streams in your terminology). They can be created and destroyed at will, but default to 3 - stdout, stdin and stderr.